# Custom Form only for admin

Tags: plugins, admin, forms

I want to add a custom form with some fields such as text,date,dropdown etc only viewable and editable for admin.When I submit the form the data should be displayed in the desired page that I select.Is there any way to do that. I dont have any idea about how to start with this. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Where should this form be visible? Should it be placed in wp-admin area or in front end?

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at my question. I want to display it in the admin area and as mentioned in the question I want to add the fields I want to be added in the form. Once data is entered into those fields and submitted, That data should be shown in the page I choose.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it won't be easy, but you can do this in this way:

1. Add a Custom Post Type (you can restrict access to this CPT for admin only).
2. Use Advanced Custom Fields plugin and create custom fields template for your Custom Post Type from 1.
3. Create a custom page template and place custom query inside it (with this query you can select custom posts).

Comment: Is there any plugin availabel to do this?

Comment: There are some plugins to add CPT. But it's pretty easy, so you can add it in code. For custom fields you can use Advanced Custom Fields plugin. I don't think there is any plugin to create custom page template (and if there is I wouldn't use it).